# Python matplotlib set color of graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a stairstep diagram with pyplot using `plt.step()`. I pass my y-values as an array of `np.array`. Now i want to color the different graphs. How can i pass a set of graph-colors, which are applied to my different graphs in the diagram?

```
yvalues = [arrayA, arrayB, arrayC]    
ycolors = ["colorA", "colorB", "colorC"]
plt.step(xvalues, yvalues, ycolors)
```

I only know how to do it value by value:

```
plt.step(xvalues, arrayA, "colorA", arrayB, "colorB", arrayC, "colorC")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with a `for` loop

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# your x data
x = np.arange(10)

# your y data
data = np.arange(1,4)[:,None] * np.arange(10)[None,:]

# your colors
color = ['k','r','g']

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

for y,c in itertools.izip(data,color):
    ax.step(x,y,c)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, i thought there would be a way to do it as a one-liner, but this will help too!